# BufferReader vs InputStream vs StringBuffer

Tags: android, android-activity

Confused too much! What is the sole purpose of using `BufferReader`, `InputStream` and `StringBuffer`. Why they should be used and in what kind of a sequence / pattern we should code them. I recently came across a chunk of code while understanding how to send and receive `HTTP` requests using `HttpUrlConnection` in android. I tried to search for all these terms and I did not get what I need. In this case, how to use each of them in a sequence or pattern? Any simple example for using all these three in combination would be great. And also kindly what should be all these 3 in layman terms? Thanks

- `InputStream` is used for reading byte based data from the web server (or url) one byte at a time.
- `BufferReader` it is used for reading data from an input stream all by once
- `StringBuffer` A modifiable sequence of characters for use in creating strings, where all accesses are synchronized. This class has mostly been replaced by StringBuilder because this synchronization is rarely useful. This class is mainly used to interact with legacy APIs that expose it. [Did not understand what it means as my official language is not English]

  ```
  //These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
  //so that they can be closed in the finally block.
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  //Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
  String forecastJsonStr = null;
  try {
  //Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
  //Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
  //http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
      URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");
      //Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
      urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
      urlConnection.connect();
      //Read the input stream into a String
      InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      if (inputStream == null) {
      //Nothing to do.
          forecastJsonStr = null;
      }
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      //Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
      //But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
      //buffer for debugging.
      buffer.append(line + "\n");
      }
      if (buffer.length() == 0) {
      //Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
          forecastJsonStr = null;
      }
      forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
      //If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
      //to parse it.
          forecastJsonStr = null;
      } finally{
          if (urlConnection != null) {
              urlConnection.disconnect();
          }
          if (reader != null) {
          try {
              reader.close();
              } catch (final IOException e) {
                  Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
  ```

Comment: there is no good reason for using `BufferedReader` to read a JSON file. Nothing allows to predict the size of the next `readLine`. Also, the InputStreamReader should explicitely set the CharSet. Finally, there are 2 tests `if (inputStream == null) {` and `if (buffer.length() == 0) {` which are pointless since they don't stop the execution. The first one will result in a direct crash. I would put this chunk of code back were I found it and leave it there.

Comment: @njzk2, you are exactly right. I know there are severe flaws in the code. As we should check the network first, if network is available then to perform further processing else show the appropriate message if no network is available. But the thing is, why, why and why we should use them and what pattern to follow. How they are different from each other?